# Druid Transform Spec for Column Explosion

Tags: druid

I am trying to find a way to parse a long string using Transform Spec string functions, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you please help with this?

Source: Kafka
Reason: Need to ingest 3000 Columns which uses lot of compute. So to avoid csv parsing made them into single column and then explode during ingestion

Eg:
IP Details:
Array: [a,b,c,d]
Column: Column_no

Expected OP:
Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4
a   |  b     |  c     |  d

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are you looking in to answer with  in SQL or any other programming language ? Please be more clear with what you required .then its easy to others to give  answer

Comment: Hey, this is not about querying, I'm trying to understand while ingestion

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the example data and expected result.
Could you post a simplified sample of what the incoming data will actually look like? Is it going to be formatted as json, or .csv, or something else?